# "Connection refused" error in a flaky unit test which involves starting an HTTP server and connecting to it

Tags: go

I'm trying to debug a flaky unit test which is similar to the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestFlaky(t *testing.T) {
    // Mock an API
    http.HandleFunc("/foo/bar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, err := w.Write([]byte("foobar"))
        require.NoError(t, err)
    })
    go func() {
        require.NoError(t, http.ListenAndServe("localhost:7777", nil))
    }()

    // Wait (up to 1 second) for the mocked API to be available
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "localhost:7777", time.Second)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.NoError(t, conn.Close())
}
```

However, from the `require.NoError()` line right after the `DialTimeout` error, I'm getting the following error (in a CI environment only):

```
     --- FAIL: TestFlaky (0.00s)
         main_test.go:24: 
                Error Trace:    main_test.go:24
                Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                dial tcp [::1]:7777: connect: connection refused
                Test:           TestFlaky
```

Since the test fails immediately, I'm guessing this is not a matter of adjusting the timeout. How should I make this test non-flaky? I'm considering replacing the last three lines with a `require.Eventually` similar to the following:

```golang
    var conn net.Conn
    require.Eventually(t, func() bool {
        var err error
        conn, err = net.DialTimeout("tcp", "localhost:7777", time.Second)
        if err != nil {
            t.Logf("DialTimeout error: %v. Retrying...", err)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }, time.Second, 100*time.Millisecond)
    require.NoError(t, conn.Close())
```

Would this suffice to remove test flakiness?

Comment: You have nothing coordinating the start of your server, http.ListenAndServe isn't guaranteed to even execute at all during the test (not to mention `t` could be accessed after the test ends, nothing is shutting down the server, and `ListenAndServe` always returns a non-nil error)). This is what the [`httptest.Server`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#Server) is for.

Comment: do you really have to spawn that conn ? for fast and reliable testing it is better to write your api such as you dont use those apis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside the goroutine does not guarantee to be executed before the Dial. (If you put a sleep just after the goroutine it should work but it is an ugly solution).

Also, notice that "dial with timeout" is waiting for tcp packets when connection is being stablished, but the refused connection is actually the RST packet.

Hint: see how httptest package works.

Edit: here is how httptest works: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/net/http/httptest/server.go;l=304

```
func (s *Server) goServe() {
    s.wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer s.wg.Done()
        s.Config.Serve(s.Listener)
    }()
}
```